# Sum of $2$-torsion points on a particular elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I'm running into some trouble trying to get some practice working with elliptic curves. Say $F$ is some field and $\lambda\in F$ is an element with $\lambda^3 \neq 27$. Let $E$ be the elliptic curve over $F$ with affine Weierestrass equation
$$
y^2 + \lambda x y + y = x^3.
$$
I'd like to understand the $2$-torsion of $E$ explicitly. See the question in bold below for what I mean by this.

If $P\in E$, then $2P=0$ if and only if $-P = P$. Using
$$
-(x,y) = (x,-y-\lambda x - 1),
$$
a little computation gives the following. First, if $-(x,y) = (x,y)$ then $y\neq 0$. So let's switch to $(z,w)$ coordinates, where
$$
z = -\frac{x}{y},\qquad w = -\frac{1}{y}.
$$
Now $E$ has equation
$$
0 = -w + z^3+\lambda zw+w^2,
$$
and the $2$-torsion points are of the form $(z,-z^3)$ where $z$ satisfies $z^4-\lambda z^2 + 2z = 0$.

**Question.** Let $P_1 = (z_1,-z_1^3)$ and $P_2 = (z_2,-z_2^3)$ be two $2$-torsion points on $E$. What is a general formula for the $z$-coordinate of $P_1+P_2$ in terms of $z_1$ and $z_2$?

(To phrase the question in fancier terms, view the elliptic curve as defined over $R = \mathbb{Z}[\lambda,(\lambda^3-27)^{-1}]$. Then the $2$-torsion $E[2]$ should be a group scheme over $R$. The above description shows it's actually affine, with coordinate ring $A = R[z]/(z^4-\lambda z^2 + 2z)$. My question is equivalent to asking for the coproduct on the Hopf algebra $A$ corresponding to the group structure on $E[2]$.)

This should be easy: just follow the recipe for addition in Silverman. Because $P_1$ and $P_2$ are $2$-torsion, if we let $L$ be the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$, then $P_1+P_2=P_3$ where $P_3 = (z_3,-z_3^3)$ is the third point in the intersection $L\cap E$. The line $L$ has equation $w = mz + b$ with
$$
m = \frac{-z_2^3 - (-z_1^3)}{z_2-z_1} = -(z_1^2+z_1z_2+z_2^2).
$$
Plugging into the equation for $E$ gives
$$
0 = -(mz+b) + z^3 + \lambda z(mz+b) + (mz+b)^2.
$$
This should have the roots $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$, and solving for $z_3$ in
$$
-(mz+b) + z^3 + \lambda z(mz+b) + (mz+b)^2 = c(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)
$$
reveals
$$
z_3 = -z_1-z_2-\lambda m - m^2 = z_1+z_2+\lambda z_1z_2-2(z_1^3z_2+z_1z_2^3)-3z_1^2z_2^2.
$$

But this can't be right. Since $P_1$ and $P_2$ are $2$-torsion, setting $z_1 = z_2 = z$ should give $0$, but instead it gives
$$
2z+\lambda z^2 - 7 z^4 = 16 z - 6 \lambda z^2.
$$

So I've made a mistake or have some misunderstanding somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: $-(x,y)$ refers to inversion on the elliptic curve, not to $(-x,-y)$.

Comment: What if there is only one 2-torsion point? Do you have an example curve with more than one?

Comment: If $F$ is algebraically closed and characteristic zero, then there must be four $2$-torsion points, so you can take $F = \overline{\mathbb{C}(\lambda)}$ with $\lambda$ some transcendental variable if you'd like. But even if there is only one $2$-torsion point, the question still makes sense, see the parenthetical after the bolded question. For example, if $F = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $\lambda = 0$, then it would be turn into a question about the $2$-torsion of the formal group of $E$.

Comment: In the case $z_1 = z_2$, your formula gives $m = -(z_1^2 + z_1 z_2 + z_2^2) = -3z_1^2$, which is the slope of the tangent line to the curve $w = -z^3$ at $z = z_1$.  I see no reason why this should agree with the slope of the tangent line to the elliptic curve, which is of course what you really want.  I haven't checked the calculations, but if the slopes are indeed different, then the cubic which you have equated with $c(z - z_1)(z - z_2)(z - z_3)$ won't be divisible by $(z - z_1)(z - z_2) = (z - z_1)^2$.

Comment: That's a good point. But it seems to mainly suggest another reason my formula is wrong, still leaving the question of how to produce a correct formula. Because $A$ is a Hopf algebra, There ought to be some formula for $z_3$ in terms of $z_1$ and $z_2$ (and $\lambda$) which returns $0$ if you set $z_1 = z_2$.

Comment: Everything you've done up until "follow the recipe for addition in Silverman" is correct, and then as Ravi Fernando points out the slope of the line you're considering there is wrong. The issue is the recipe for addition in Silverman has some caveats - those formulas don't quite work for doubling points and you have to do extra work to get around that (see Silverman AEC II theorem IV.5.3c for something close). I don't know the right function, but the answer for the $z$-coordinate is $-z_1-z_2$ if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are distinct and nonzero; $z_1$ if $z_1\neq 0$ and $z_2=0$, and $0$ if $z_1=z_2$.

Comment: Yes, the work after the bolded question must be wrong, that's why I've asked the question! Knowing that it's wrong just hasn't helped me find what's right. The Hopf algebra interpretation shows that there should be a non-piecewise formula. I don't know what calculation leads to your $-z_1-z_2$.

Answer (score -1):

$$E:Y^2 + (1+\lambda X)Y - X^3=0$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto (x,-1-\lambda x-y)$$ is an automorphism of $E$, leaving $O=(\infty,\infty)$ fixed.

This must be our $(x,y)\mapsto -(x,y)$ map.

You can check that $\{ (x,y), y = -1-\lambda x-y\} $ gives a cubic equation in $x$ so it contains 3 elements $P_1,P_2,P_3$.

Then $E[2] = \{ O,P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ and the group law is $2P_i =O, P_i+P_j = P_l,i\ne j\ne l$.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. I don't want $E[2]$ as an abstract group, I really do want to ask the question I asked. (My formula for the inversion had a typo with a $z$ instead of a $1$, which I've now fixed, but that doesn't affect anything else in the question).

Comment: Unclear what you mean, you didn't even fix $\lambda$ so the coordinates of $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are the roots of some kind of general cubic polynomial. It is not hard to check that the group law acts the way I said, which is your question in bold.

Comment: Yes, and I would like a formula for $P_3$ in terms of $P_1$ and $P_2$. To phrase the question in fancier language, view the elliptic curve as defined over $R = \mathbb{Z}[\lambda,(\lambda^3-27)^{-1}]$. The $2$-torsion $E[2]$ defines a group scheme over $R$, and the given description of $2$-torsion points on $E$ shows that $E[2]$ is affine with coordinate ring $A = R[z]/(z^4-\lambda z^2 + 2z)$. My question is equivalent to asking for a formula for the coproduct on the Hopf algebra $A$ corresponding to the group structure on $E[2]$.

Comment: The $x$ of $P_3$ is the 3rd root of the cubic polynomial $$(\frac{-1-\lambda x}{2})^2 + (1+\lambda x)\frac{-1-\lambda x}{2} - x^3$$

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking for. Maybe it leads to an answer to my question, but since I've been having trouble with these manipulations, I would like to see an answer to the question as it is asked (working with the $z$-coordinate). I've edited to try and clarify the question.

Comment: You are over-complicating. This cubic polynomial has 3 roots, the $x$-coordinates of $P_1,P_2,P_3$, the $y$ coordinates are $(-1-\lambda x)/2$, and $P_i+P_j=P_l$. If you know $P_1,P_2$ then $P_3$ is found easily from the constant coefficient of the cubic polynomial. Not much more to say unless you fix $\lambda$.

Comment: I'm not over-complicating. I may be asking a more complicated question, but that more complicated question really is what I want to ask! (I am in fact interested in that Hopf algebra, and that formulation of the question shows that there is something to say without fixing $\lambda$).